# Smallest item in given position in 2d arrray

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I ran into this problem while using Python3. I have this 2d array (a list containing lists if you may) and I want to pick apart the item which has the smallest number in position [0]

As an example:

```
[[6, 'lorem'], [7, 'ipsum'], [3, 'dolor'], [4, 'sit']]
```

Should return `[3, 'dolor']`

Comment: Why not using `min`?

Comment: I didn't know how to use it inside a 2d array before being answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `min`:

```
l=[[6, 'lorem'], [7, 'ipsum'], [3, 'dolor'], [4, 'sit']]
print(min(l,key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Or can do `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter as g
l=[[6, 'lorem'], [7, 'ipsum'], [3, 'dolor'], [4, 'sit']]
print(min(l,key=g(0)))
```

Now here do direct `min`:

```
l=[[6, 'lorem'], [7, 'ipsum'], [3, 'dolor'], [4, 'sit']]
print(min(l))
```

Comment: `key=lambda x: x[0]` is unnecessary, lexicographical order is already the default

Comment: @Julien added two others

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sorted` and then pull the item at position `0`

```
l = [[6, 'lorem'], [7, 'ipsum'], [3, 'dolor'], [4, 'sit']]
l = sorted(l)[0]
```

> ```
> [3, 'dolor']
> ```